# unsupervised learning how to get number of clusters

Tags: machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

In this code below the author says that -

"Before I begin the kmeans clustering I want to use a hierarchial clustering to figure how many clusters I should have. I truncated the dendrogram because if I didn't the dendrogram will be hard to read. I cut at 20 because it has the second biggest distance jump (the first big jump is at 60). After the cut there are 7 clusters."

I am not able to see in the Dendrogram how he arrived at the numbers he mentioned - 20, 60 or 7
I am attaching the dendrogram that I have got from the sample data taken from his github example and am wondering if anyone can shed light on how he arrived at the numbers 20, 60 or 7

he also says "Let's fit k-means on the matrix with a range of clusters 1 - 19." where did he get that range 1 to 19 from? is it cause of the drop at 20 (or the cut off at 20)

github - https://github.com/moyphilip/SKU-Clustering

[image]

Also what would one say should be the number of clusters in this second image attached here  ? 6 clusters ? (its a different dataset)

[image]

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('sample-data.csv')




def split_description(string):
    string_split = string.split(' - ',1)
    name = string_split[0]

    return name


df_new = pd.DataFrame()
df_new['name'] = df.loc[:,'description'].apply(lambda x: split_description(x))
df_new['id'] = df['id']

def remove(name):
    new_name = re.sub("[0-9]", '', name)
    new_name = ' '.join(new_name.split())
    return new_name



df_new['name'] = df_new.loc[:,'name'].apply(lambda x: remove(x))

df_new.head()




tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
                                   use_idf=True,
                                   stop_words = 'english',
                                   ngram_range=(1,4), min_df = 0.01, max_df = 0.8)


tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(df_new['name'])


print (tfidf_matrix.shape)
print (tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names())


from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
dist = 1.0 - cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix)
print (dist)

from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import ward, dendrogram

#run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
linkage_matrix = ward(dist) #define the linkage_matrix using ward clustering pre-computed distances

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 20)) # set size
ax = dendrogram(linkage_matrix,
                truncate_mode='lastp', # show only the last p merged clusters
                p=20, # show only the last p merged clusters
                leaf_rotation=90.,
                leaf_font_size=12.,
                labels=list(df_new['name']))

plt.axhline(y=20, linewidth = 2, color = 'black')

fig.suptitle("Hierarchial Clustering Dendrogram Truncated", fontsize = 35, fontweight = 'bold')

#fig.show()

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
num_clusters = range(1,20)

KM = [KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state = 1).fit(tfidf_matrix) for k in num_clusters]


# Let's plot the within cluster sum of squares for each k to see which k I should choose.
# 
# The plot shows a steady decline from from 0 to 19. Since the elbow rule does not apply for this I will choose k = 7 because of the previous dendrogram.

# In[17]:


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
with_in_cluster = [KM[k].inertia_ for k in range(0,len(num_clusters))]
plt.plot(num_clusters, with_in_cluster)
plt.ylim(min(with_in_cluster)-1000, max(with_in_cluster)+1000)
plt.ylabel('with-in cluster sum of squares')
plt.xlabel('# of clusters')
plt.title('kmeans within ss for k value')
plt.show()


# I add the cluster label to each record in df_new

# In[18]:


model = KM[6]
clusters = model.labels_.tolist()
df_new['cluster'] = clusters


# Here is the distribution of clusters. Cluster 0 has a records, then cluster 1. Cluster 2 - 4 seem pretty even.

# In[19]:


df_new['cluster'].value_counts()


# I print the top terms per cluster and the names in the respective cluster.

# In[20]:


print("Top terms per cluster:")
print
order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(model.n_clusters):
    print ("Cluster %d : " %i )
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print ( '%s' % terms[ind])
    print
    print ("Cluster %d names:" %i)
    for idx in df_new[df_new['cluster'] == i]['name'].sample(n = 10):
        print ( ' %s' %idx)
    print
    print


# I reduce the dist to 2 dimensions with MDS. The dissimilarity is precomputed because we provide 1 - cosine similarity. Then I assign the x and y variables.

# In[21]:


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

from sklearn.manifold import MDS

mds = MDS(n_components=2, dissimilarity="precomputed", random_state=1)

pos = mds.fit_transform(dist)

xs, ys = pos[:, 0], pos[:, 1]


# In[22]:


cluster_colors = {0: '#85C1E9', 1: '#FF0000', 2: '#800000', 3: '#04B320', 
                  4: '#6033FF', 5: '#33FF49', 6: '#F9E79F', 7: '#935116',
                  8: '#9B59B6', 9: '#95A5A6'}
cluster_labels = {0: 'vest  dress  print', 1: 'shirt  merino  island',
                  2: 'pants  guide pants  guide', 3: 'shorts  board  board shorts',
                  4: 'simply  live  live simply', 5: 'cap  cap bottoms  bottoms',
                  6: 'jkt  zip jkt  guide'}

#some ipython magic to show the matplotlib plots inline
#get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

#create data frame that has the result of the MDS plus the cluster numbers and titles
df_plot = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=xs, y=ys, label=clusters, name=df_new['name'])) 

#group by cluster
groups = df_plot.groupby('label')

# set up plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(17, 9)) # set size

for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.x, group.y, marker='o', linestyle='', ms=12,
            label = cluster_labels[name], 
            color = cluster_colors[name])
    ax.set_aspect('auto')

ax.legend(numpoints = 1)  

fig.suptitle("SKU Clustering", fontsize = 35, fontweight = 'bold')

#plt.show()
```

Comment: "I cut at 20" is referring to the y-axis. Note how there is a black horizontal line at y=20. That black horizontal line crosses 6 vertical lines (1 blue line and 5 green lines). Each vertical line corresponds to one cluster, so that means the cut at 20 will cross 6 clusters. Note that this count of 6 clusters differs from what the author wrote, "After the cut there are 7 clusters".

Comment: yes, I did see that he meant the y axis for the 20, but how did he arrive at 20 , guess as the bar chart height change is what he means by drop. and yes I agree with u it is 6 and not 7